# Unity3D C#, PHP via WWW is not work correctly in project but works on empty project

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

We are designing a game for a school project. We have a php file that show high scores. When we look the php page on internet, it works correctly, when we create new project with same C# code (100% same), it works also but in our project, WWW returns empty result. What can be the reason?

(Example output is taken in new empty project)   "Stewie|2150;Automatic|2000;Tarik|450;Rush|320;skadoodle|300;"

Note: We have 6 php files, all of them tested in empty project and works correctly. 5 of them works correctly in main project but one of the returns empty.

Example code:

```
public void Get_Top_5_HighScores()
{
    StartCoroutine(Get_Highscores_From_Database());
}

IEnumerator Get_Highscores_From_Database()
{

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    WWW scorephp = new WWW(highscores_url, form);
    yield return scorephp;

    Debug.Log("Scorephp: " + scorephp.text);
    // On another project (Empty project for test) it works correctly.
    // But in game, it prints empty value.

    // Parser codes continue...

}
```

Comment: What is inside your project that isn't in a new project?

Comment: RPG game as a  graduation project for University

Comment: Have you checked that the input forwarded to the non-functioning file is exactly the same as expected on both sides of the transfer? Combing through your code with debugs and breakpoints seem like a good idea here, assuming you haven't already done that.